# Serializing a table for filing

Tags: performance, c, serialization, lua, lua-table

I have a table in Lua, which contains two 1-dimensional arrays in which each array contains approximately 800,000 elements. I want to serialize this Lua table to file efficiently. Hence, I planned to use Lua C bindings.

```
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

static int do_it(lua_State *L) {
  assert(L && lua_type(L, -1) == LUA_TTABLE);

  int len, idx;
  void *ptr;
  FILE *f;
  size_t r;

  lua_pushstring(L, "p");
  lua_gettable(L, -2);
  len = lua_objlen(L, -1);
  // instead of using lua_rawlen, i used lua_objlen. see below
  // len = lua_rawlen(L, -1); // it throws the following error
  // lua: error loading module 'savetable' from file './savetable.so':
  //    ./savetable.so: undefined symbol: lua_rawlen
  int p_values[len];
  for (idx = 1; idx <= len; idx++) {
    lua_rawgeti(L, -1, idx);
    p_values[idx - 1] = (int)lua_tonumber(L, -1);
    lua_pop(L, 1);
  }

  f = fopen("p.bin", "wb");
  assert(f);
  r = fwrite(p_values, sizeof(int), len, f);
  printf("[p] wrote %zu elements out of %d requested\n", r, len);
  fclose(f);
  lua_pop(L, 1);

  lua_pushstring(L, "q");
  lua_gettable(L, -2);
  len = lua_objlen(L, -1);
  double q_values[len];
  for (idx = 1; idx <= len; idx++) {
    lua_rawgeti(L, -1, idx);
    q_values[idx - 1] = (double)lua_tonumber(L, -1);
    lua_pop(L, 1);
  }

  f = fopen("q.bin", "wb");
  assert(f);
  r = fwrite(q_values, sizeof(double), len, f);
  printf("[q] wrote %zu elements out of %d requested\n", r, len);
  fclose(f);
  lua_pop(L, 1);

  return 1;
}

int luaopen_savetable(lua_State *L) {
  static const luaL_reg Map[] = {{"do_it", do_it}, {NULL, NULL}};

  luaL_register(L, "mytask", Map);
  return 1;
}
```

Please note that for debugging purpose, I have defined two very small 1-dimensional arrays:

```
my_table = {p = {11, 22, 33, 44}, q = {0.12, 0.23, 0.34, 0.45, 0.56}}

require "savetable"
mytask.do_it(my_table)
```

I used the following commands to compile and run it:

```
> gcc -I/usr/include/lua5.1 -o savetable.so -shared savetable.c -fPIC
> lua wrapper.lua
```

The code works, however, I am looking for suggestions to make table serialization to file much faster than current.

Please note that I am using Lua 5.1 on a 64-bit Ubuntu PC.

Comment: Tip: you may write your array implementation in C and push it into Lua as a light userdata with custom metatable (with insert/remove methods). If you make your array continuous you may use it directly from C w/o Lua stack functions.

Comment: @sineemore: Thank you very much for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I didn't get it completely. Let me tell you that I have a table of two large arrays inside Lua. In order to serialize it quickly, I am using Lua C bindings. Well, can you please explain your suggestion a bit more? Or may I ask you to provide a reference to what exactly you are suggesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// undefined symbol: lua_rawlen
```

This happens because there is no such function in Lua 5.1 C API. As stated by documentation `lua_objlen` is preffered way to get table length.

FYI `lua_rawlen` function first appeared in Lua 5.2.

It is very handy to check [Lua Reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/) to see availiable C API for particular Lua version.

---

## Serialization with zero latency

Wow, that title stands out. Let me explain what I mean: serialization with zero latency means there is *no serialization at all*.

Watch out: it heavely depends on the origin of your table.

The caveats:

- you must control the table creation
- only inserts, no removes

If this is the case, follow on:

As you stated your table is actually an array of Lua numbers. In C Lua number is `lua_Number` which is probably a `double` value.

We can create a custom table implementation to only store Lua numbers in it.
The table will be continuos memory with `lua_Number` members in it.

```
typedef struct {
    lua_Number *items;
    size_t len; // number of entries in items
    size_t cap; // maximum `len` value before we will `realloc(items)`
} fasterarray;
```

To provide `fasterarray` we'll use `lua_newuserdata`. It will allocate memory that will be watched by Lua garbage collector. In particular when there is no more references the allocated userdata will be collected.

```
static int new(lua_State *L) {
    fasterarray *fa = lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(fasterarray));
    luaL_getmetatable(L, NAME); // <-- setting metatable, see below
    lua_setmetatable(L, -2);    // <--
    fa->len = 0;
    fa->cap = 8;
    fa->items = calloc(fa->cap * sizeof(lua_Number), 1);
    return 1;
}
```

Insert function will realloc `items` when more space is needed.

```
static int insert(lua_State *L) {
    fasterarray *fa = lua_touserdata(L, 1);
    lua_Number num = lua_tonumber(L, 2);
    if (fa->len == fa->cap) {
        fa->cap *= 2;
        fa->items = realloc(fa->items, fa->cap * sizeof(lua_Number));
        assert(fa && fa->items);
    }
    fa->items[fa->len++] = num;
    return 0;
}
```

Important part of this implementation is garbage collection. `userdata` will be collected by Lua automagically, but the memory behind `items` must be freed directly in C. To handle this we will use `__gc` metatable method.

```
static int gc(lua_State *L) {
    fasterarray *fa = lua_touserdata(L, 1);
    if (fa && fa->items) free(fa->items);
    printf("gc\n");
    return 0;
}
```

#### Full example:

**fasterarray.c**

```
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define NAME "fasterarray"

typedef struct {
    lua_Number *items;
    size_t len;
    size_t cap;
} fasterarray;

static int new(lua_State *L) {
    fasterarray *fa = lua_newuserdata(L, sizeof(fasterarray));
    luaL_getmetatable(L, NAME);
    lua_setmetatable(L, -2);
    fa->len = 0;
    fa->cap = 8;
    fa->items = calloc(fa->cap * sizeof(lua_Number), 1);
    return 1;
}

static int gc(lua_State *L) {
    fasterarray *fa = lua_touserdata(L, 1);
    if (fa && fa->items) free(fa->items);
    printf("gc\n");
    return 0;
}

static int insert(lua_State *L) {
    fasterarray *fa = lua_touserdata(L, 1);
    lua_Number num = lua_tonumber(L, 2);
    if (fa->len == fa->cap) {
        fa->cap *= 2;
        fa->items = realloc(fa->items, fa->cap * sizeof(lua_Number));
        assert(fa && fa->items);
    }
    fa->items[fa->len++] = num;
    return 0;
}

int luaopen_fasterarray(lua_State *L) {

    // fasterarray metatable
    luaL_newmetatable(L, NAME);
    luaL_register(L, NULL, (luaL_Reg []) {
        {"__gc", gc},
        {NULL, NULL}
    });

    // exported funcs
    luaL_register(L, NAME, (luaL_Reg []) {
        {"new", new},
        {"insert", insert},
        {NULL, NULL}
    });
    return 1;
}
```

**example.lua**

```
require"fasterarray"

local ar = fasterarray.new()
local i = 700000
while i > 0 do
        fasterarray.insert(ar, i)
        i = i - 1
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed suggestion. I must tell you that the large Lua arrays are returned from an external API (inside Lua script). Hence,  I have no control over the creation of the array.  Please also note that I am looking for serialization to file. Therefore I want to pass the file name along with the array while serializing the file. Any suggestions, please?

Comment: @RaviJoshi, This might help: you may create this specific array I provided and insert all elements from vendor array into it. Since it resides in continuos memory you may dump it directly to file.